# React router v6: how to get relative index path in component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How can I get the relative index path, not including subroutes, from a component in react router? For example:

index.js:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
        <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />}>
          <Route path="advanced" element={<Advanced />}>
            <Route path="edit-teams" element={<Teams />}>
              <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

When I visit the URLs `teams` or `teams/1`, I want to be able to get the value `teams` (the root relative URL) from within the `Teams` component. When I visit `settings/advanced/edit-teams` or `settings/advanced/edit-teams/1`, the value should be `settings/advanced/edit-teams`

What I've tried so far:

```
const Teams = () => {
  //this gives me "settings/advanced/edit-teams/1" instead of "settings/advanced/edit-teams" when I visit "settings/advanced/edit-teams/1"
  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      Teams
      <Outlet />
      <button onClick={() => navigate(pathname)}>Back to Teams</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service, what have you tried already? Can you update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Are you trying to compute what the route rendering the `Teams` component is being matched, where/which `Teams` component is rendered? What is the use case?

Comment: @DrewReese So basically the `Teams` component is being mounted in many different paths. I've just shown 2 in the example for simplicity. I have a button in the `Teams` component that redirects to the relative index path. For example, if I'm in `settings/advanced/edit-teams/1`, clicking the button will take the user back to `settings/advanced/edit-teams`. Therefore I need to know this relative index path from within the `Teams` component. I have tried using `useLocation` but this just gives me the entire path (i.e `settings/advanced/edit-teams/1`)

Comment: Please share all the relevant code you are trying to use and work with. I think I understand what you are trying/wanting to do, but we should see the code to understand what it is *actually* doing, so we can provide a solution. This seems like an XY-problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems all you need in the `Teams` component is to navigate to the route's `path` it's rendered on. For this you can navigate to `"."`.

Example:

```
const Teams = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      Teams
      <Outlet />
      <button onClick={() => navigate(".")}>Back to Teams</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Consider routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route path="teams" element={<Teams />}>
      <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />}>
      <Route path="advanced" element={<Advanced />}>
        <Route path="edit-teams" element={<Teams />}>
          <Route path=":teamId" element={<Team />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

A `Teams` component is rendered on `"/settings/advanced/edit-teams"`, so navigating to `"."` will navigate to this path.

[image: Edit react-router-v6-how-to-get-relative-index-path-in-component]